# Bidirectional typing effect

Tags: javascript, html

Implementation supporting both typing directions from left to right and from right to left. It also supports alternating typing directions and configurable letter spacing. With monospace font the typed line extends and narrow fluently.
Developed around `innerText` method of `HTMLElement` to display the text to type and `innerHTML` method of `HTMLElement` to change the letter spacing.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.loading .show { opacity: 0; }
.show { transition: opacity .5s linear; }
.alternative-text { font-size: 48px; color: gray; text-align: center; }
.sized { height: 10%; width: 50%; }
.centered {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.whisperer { font-size: 48px; color: #efefef; text-align: center; transition: opacity .5s linear; }
.transition .whisperer { opacity: 0; }
</style>
</head>
<body class="loading">
<div class="show centered sized">
    <div class="alternative-text">...</div>
    <div class="whisperer">loose alternate</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var shifter = (function() {
    
    return { supply: function(purpose) {
        
        return (function() {
            
            var callees = [ (purpose || (() => {})) ];
            
            return { schedule: function(shiftFunction) {
            
                         var calleesArray = callees;
                         var callee = () => {
                             calleesArray.shift();
                             shiftFunction();
                         };
                         calleesArray.unshift(callee);
                         return this;
                   }
                   , shift: function() {
                         callees[0]();
                   }
};})();}};})();
var Diffuser = (function() {
    return { supply: function() {
        return (function() {
            var diffusees = [];
            var oneTimeDiffusees = [];
            
            var withdraw = function (value) {

                var once = function(values) {
                    var index = values.indexOf(value);
                    if ( index > -1 ) {
                        values.splice(index, 1);

                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                };
                var remover = once;

                return { from: function(values) {
                                   return remover(values);
                         }
                       , entierly: function() {

                                       remover = function(values) {
                                                     var index = values.indexOf(value);
                                                     if ( index == -1 ) { return false; }
                                                     for ( var i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
                                                         if ( values[i] === value ) {
                                                             values.splice(i, 1);
                                                         }
                                                     }
                                                     return true;
                                                 };

                                       return this;
                       }
                     , once: function() {

                                 remover = once;

                                 return this;
                     }};
            };
            
            return {
                diffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
                    diffusees.push(diffusee);
                    return true;
                }
                , oneTimeDiffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
                    oneTimeDiffusees.push(diffusee);
                    return true;
                }
                , withdraw: function(diffusee) {
                    return withdraw(diffusee).from(diffusees);
                }
                , withdrawOneTimeDiffusee: function(diffusee) {
                    return withdraw(diffusee).from(oneTimeDiffusees);
                }
                , diffuse: function() {
                    var diffuseFunction = function() {
                        diffusees.forEach( (diffusee) => { (function() { diffusee(); })(); });
                    };
                    var oneTimeDiffuseFunction = function() {
                        for ( var i = 0; i < oneTimeDiffusees.length; i++ ) {
                            var diffusee = oneTimeDiffusees.pop();
                            if ( !(function() { return diffusee(); })() ) {
                                oneTimeDiffusees.push(diffusee);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    
                    setTimeout( function() { 
                        
                        diffuseFunction();
                        oneTimeDiffuseFunction();
                        
                    }, 0);
                }
            };
        })();
    } };
})();
var unfold = function(text) {
    return (function() {
        
        var area = void(0);
        
        var renderPlaceholder = function() {
            var placeholder = "";
            var placeholderChar = "";
            for ( var i = 0; i < modeSource.mode().characterMultiplier(); i++) {
                placeholderChar += "&nbsp;";
            }
            for ( var i = 0; i < text.length - 1; i++ ) {
                placeholder += placeholderChar;
            }
            area.innerHTML = placeholder + "&nbsp;"; 
        };
        
        var resetArea = function() {
            area.innerText = text;
        };
        
        var mode = function() {
            
            var loose = { characterMultiplier: 2};
            var plain = { characterMultiplier: 1};
            var mode = loose;
            
            return {
                plain: function() {
                    mode = plain;
                    return this;
                }
                , loose: function() {
                    mode = loose;
                    return this;
                }
                , characterMultiplier: function() {
                    return mode.characterMultiplier;
                }
            };
        };
        
        var renderer = function(charSource, modeSource) {

            return (function() {
            
                        var renderedSymbolIndex = 0;
                        var indexForwarder = function(index) { return index + 1; };
                        var forwardReturner = function(toReturn) { return toReturn; };
                        var nextIndex = indexForwarder;
                        var toReturn = forwardReturner;
                        var renderDoneDiffuser = Diffuser.supply();
                        
                        return { forward: function() {
                                     nextIndex = indexForwarder;
                                     toReturn = forwardReturner;
                                     return this;
                               }
                               , reverse: function() {
                                     nextIndex = function(index) { return index - 1; };
                                     toReturn = function(toReturn) { return text.length - 1 - toReturn; };
                                     this.reset = function() { renderedSymbolIndex = text.length - 1; return this; };
                                     this.reset();
                                     return this;
                               }
                               , render: function() {
                                     var rendered = Array.from(area.innerText);
                                     rendered[renderedSymbolIndex * modeSource.mode().characterMultiplier()] = charSource(renderedSymbolIndex);
                                     area.innerHTML = rendered.join("");
                                     var returnee = renderedSymbolIndex;
                                     renderedSymbolIndex = nextIndex(renderedSymbolIndex);
                                     if ( toReturn(returnee) == text.length - 1 ) {
                                         renderDoneDiffuser.diffuse();
                                     }
                               }
                               , reset: function() {
                                     renderedSymbolIndex = 0;
                                     return this;
                               }
                               , renderDoneDiffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
                                   return renderDoneDiffuser.diffuseTo(diffusee);
                               }
                               , withdrawRenderDoneDifusee: function(diffusee) {
                                   return renderDoneDiffuser.withdraw(diffusee);
                               }
                               , renderDoneOneTimeDiffuseTo: function(diffusee) {
                                   return renderDoneDiffuser.oneTimeDiffuseTo(diffusee);
                               }
                               , withdrawRenderDoneOneTimeDiffusee: function(diffusee) {
                                   return renderDoneDiffuser.withdrawOneTimeDiffusee(diffusee);
                               }};
        })()};
        
        var charFromTextSource = (renderedSymbolIndex) => { return text.charAt(renderedSymbolIndex); };
        var spaceCharSource = (renderedSymbolIndex) => { return "&nbsp;"; };
        var modeSource = ( function(mode) {
            
            var modeHolder = mode;
            
            return {
                mode: function() { return mode; }
                , newMode: function(newMode) { mode = newMode; }
            };
        })(mode().loose());
        
        var forwardRenderer = renderer(charFromTextSource, modeSource);
        var forwardEraser = renderer(spaceCharSource, modeSource);
        var reversedRenderer = renderer(charFromTextSource, modeSource).reverse();
        var reversedEraser = renderer(spaceCharSource, modeSource).reverse();

        var forwardRenderers = [ forwardRenderer, forwardEraser ];
        var reverseRenderers = [ reversedRenderer, reversedEraser ];
        var alternateRenderers = [ forwardRenderer, forwardEraser, reversedRenderer, reversedEraser ];
        var wobbleRenderers = [ forwardRenderer, reversedEraser, reversedRenderer, forwardEraser];
        
        var rendererShifter = shifter.supply();
        
        var renderDoneDiffusee = function() { 
            var activeRenders = renders[0]; 
            activeRenders.push( activeRenders.shift().reset() ); 
        };
        forwardRenderer.renderDoneDiffuseTo( renderDoneDiffusee );
        forwardEraser.renderDoneDiffuseTo( renderDoneDiffusee );
        reversedRenderer.renderDoneDiffuseTo( renderDoneDiffusee );
        reversedEraser.renderDoneDiffuseTo( renderDoneDiffusee );
        
        var eraseDoneDifusee = function() { rendererShifter.shift(); };
        forwardEraser.renderDoneDiffuseTo( eraseDoneDifusee );
        reversedEraser.renderDoneDiffuseTo( eraseDoneDifusee );

        var modeChanger = ( function(renders) {
            
            var runner = function(newMode) { modeSource.newMode(newMode); };
            var scheduler = function(newMode) {

                var changeLayoutShifter = shifter.supply().schedule( () => {
                    resetArea();
                    modeSource.newMode(newMode);
                    renderPlaceholder();
                });

                var changeLayoutDiffusee = function() {
                    changeLayoutShifter.shift();
                    return true;
                };

                for ( var i = 0; i < renders.length; i++ ) {
                    renders[i].renderDoneOneTimeDiffuseTo(changeLayoutDiffusee);
                }
            };
            var handler = runner;
            return { newMode: function(newMode) { handler(newMode); }
                   , schedule: function() { handler = scheduler; }
                   , run: function() { handler = runner; }
            };
        })([forwardEraser, reversedEraser]);
        
        var renders = [ forwardRenderers, reverseRenderers, alternateRenderers, wobbleRenderers ];
        
        var shiftRendersTo = function(activeRenders) {
            
            while ( activeRenders !== renders[0] ) {
                renders.push( renders.shift() );
            }
        };

        var freezeShifter = shifter.supply();
        var freeze = function() {
            modeChanger.run();
            freezeShifter.shift();
        };
        var continuousRender = function() {
            if ( nextFreeze ) { freeze(); return; }
            
            renders[0][0].render();
            
            setTimeout( () => { continuousRender(); }, 500);
        };
        var nextFreeze = false;
        var returnee =  { on: function(element) { 
                              area = element;
                              return this;
                        }, layout: { plain: function() {
                                         modeChanger.newMode(mode().plain());
                                         return returnee;
                                   }, loose: function() {
                                         modeChanger.newMode(mode().loose());
                                         return returnee;
                                   }
                        }, forward: function() {
                              shiftRendersTo(forwardRenderers);
                              return this;
                        }, reverse: function() {
                              shiftRendersTo(reverseRenderers);
                              return this;
                        }, alternate: function() {
                              shiftRendersTo(alternateRenderers);
                              return this;
                        }, wobble: function() {
                              shiftRendersTo(wobbleRenderers);
                              return this;
                        }, now: function() {
                              if ( !area ) { console.log("unfold where?"); return this; }
                              modeChanger.schedule();
                              renderPlaceholder();
                              continuousRender();
                              return this;
                        }, shiftTo: function() {
                              var context = this;
                              return {
                                  forward: function() {
                                  rendererShifter.schedule(function() { shiftRendersTo(forwardRenderers); });
                                  return context;
                              }, reverse: function() {
                                  rendererShifter.schedule(function() { shiftRendersTo(reverseRenderers); });
                                  return context;
                              }, alternate: function() {
                                  rendererShifter.schedule(function() { shiftRendersTo(alternateRenderers); });
                                  return context;
                              }, wobble: function() {
                                  rendererShifter.schedule(function() { shiftRendersTo(wobbleRenderers); });
                                  return context;
                              } };
                        }, freeze: function(freezeTopping) {
                              nextFreeze = true;
                              freezeShifter.schedule(freezeTopping);
                              return this;
                        }, reset: function() {
                              resetArea();
                              return this;
                        }, unfoldedDiffusedTo: function(diffusee) {
                              forwardRenderer.renderDoneDiffuseTo(diffusee);
                              reversedRenderer.renderDoneDiffuseTo(diffusee);
                              return this;
                        }, unfoldedOneTimeDiffusedTo: function(diffusee) {
                              forwardRenderer.renderDoneOneTimeDiffuseTo(diffusee);
                              reversedRenderer.renderDoneOneTimeDiffuseTo(diffusee);
                              return this;
                        }, withdrawUnfoldedDiffusee: function(diffusee) {
                              forwardRenderer.withdrawRenderDoneDifusee(diffusee);
                              reversedRenderer.withdrawRenderDoneDifusee(diffusee);
                              return this;
        }};
        return returnee;
    })();
};
var vainer = (function() {
    return { supply: (purpose) => {
        var vainers = [() => { return false; }];
        if ( purpose ) { vainers.unshift(() => { vainers.shift(); return purpose(); }); }
        return { shift: function() { return vainers[0](); }
               , schedule: function(schedulee) { 
                   vainers.unshift( () => { vainers.shift(); return schedulee(); } );
                   return this;
               }
        };
    }};
})();
var wind = unfold("...").on(document.querySelector(".alternative-text")).alternate().now();
(function() {
    
    var whisperer = (function(element) {
        var cssTransition = "transition";
        var fadeoutMillis = 500;
        var text = { it: (textee) => {
            element.parentNode.classList.add(cssTransition);
            setTimeout(() => { element.innerText = textee; }, fadeoutMillis);
            setTimeout(() => { element.parentNode.classList.remove(cssTransition); }, 1010);
        } };
        return { whisper: (whisper) => { text.it(whisper); return this; } };
    })(document.querySelector(".whisperer"));

    var delayMillis = 12000;
    var mode = vainer.supply()
                     .schedule(() => { wind.shiftTo().forward(); whisperer.whisper("loose forward"); return delayMillis;})
                     .schedule(() => { wind.shiftTo().reverse(); whisperer.whisper("loose reverse"); return delayMillis;})
                     .schedule(() => { wind.shiftTo().wobble(); whisperer.whisper("loose wobble"); return delayMillis;})
                     .schedule(() => { wind.layout.loose(); wind.shiftTo().forward(); whisperer.whisper("loose forward"); return delayMillis;})
                     .schedule(() => { wind.layout.plain(); whisperer.whisper("plain alternate"); return delayMillis;})
                     .schedule(() => { return delayMillis;});
    
    var changer = () => {
        var delayMillis = mode.shift();
        if ( delayMillis == false ) { return; }
        setTimeout(() => { changer(); }, delayMillis);
    };
    changer();
    setTimeout(() => { document.body.classList.remove("loading"); }, 1000);
} )();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a typing effect on firefox, just text fading in and out and 3 "loading" dots. I don't understand the point of the app, but in any case, [formatting with Prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/) is encouraged. There are long lines with multiple expressions that should be on separate lines.